# Unexpected display of icon in DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm having a problem with my DataTable displaying an icon in a strange way ONLY before page refresh. That is when I refresh the page it displays as normal.

See: 
[image: Icon issue]

Here is my `innerHTML` code for this col:

```
tblTds[2].innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="deleteItem(' + "'" + aData[2] + "'" + ');"><i style="color:red" class="fa fa-times" title="Delete Item" id="item' + aData[2] + '"></i></a>';
```

I can't figure out what's happening, has anyone seen this or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is why the better practice is add html from html. Which reduces the chance of making mistakes.

```js
   
var addNewDeleteItem = function(tableCell, onClickEvent) {
  var deleteElement = document.getElementById("delete-icon-template");      
  deleteElement.removeAttribute("id");
  var html = deleteElement.outerHTML;
  deleteElement.onClick = onClickEvent;
  tableCell.innerHTML = html;
  
}

addNewDeleteItem(tblTds[2], deleteItem()); // aData[2] should be catch from that click event's raise point.
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="hide">
  <a id="delete-icon-template" onClick="" class="fa fa-times" title="delete"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your call to deleteItem method is incorrect. Need to use escape characters.
Something like -

```
tblTds[2].innerHTML = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"deleteItem('" + aData[2] + "');\"><i style=\"color:red\" class=\"fa fa-times\" title=\"Delete Item\" id=\"item" + aData[2] + "\"></i></a>";
```

Why your code works after refresh ? - For that you need to compare innerHTML before and after refresh.

Comment: thanks for the tip on comparing innerhtml before and after, it helped